# match parent and inner index within nested ng-repeats while passing duplicate values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to pass duplicate values in different formats but can not match parent and inner indexes hence I get `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]`. that said, I pass object with multiple properties among which I have tags...see below

`vm.hotels` returns objects like below

```
0:object
  tags:"tag1|tag2|tag3"
1:object
  tags:"tag1|tag2|tag3"
```

`vm.hTags` is an array that matches each object like below

```
["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
```

within my controller I split tags and push then into an array within a loop which I pass to the view. this works as it should but I can not make it work with indexes within the view. below are nested `ng-repeat`s

```
<li ng-repeat="item in vm.hotels track by $index">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="tag in vm.hTags[$index]">
            {{tag}}   
        </li>
    </ul>
<li>
```

I tried to use `vm.hTags[$parent.$index]` but it does not work as duplicate error is thrown due to indexes. Perhaps I need to create some custom tracking property ?

Comment: Show your hotels object.

Comment: @HJz error is gone but no output

Comment: @ManikandanVelayutham I did show object 0:object tags:"tag1||tag2", 1:object tags:"tag1||tag2"

Comment: @user1751287 provide all the arrays used in your repeat clearly

Comment: @tanmay please see edit with data. so each object gets matching array with data

Comment: @user1751287 added my answer. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with nested `ng-repeat` is that is that if you use `$index` for both child and parent, it might conflict. In order to avoid it, we can use it by giving name. Like this

`ng-repeat="(hotelIndex, item) in vm.hotels ..."`

I don't know how you want to render it but here's a sample example of that:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.hotels = [{
    tags: "tag1|tag2|tag3"
  }, {
    tags: "tag4|tag5|tag6"
  }]
  vm.hTags = [["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"], ["tag4", "tag5", "tag6"]]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <div ng-repeat="(hotelIndex, item) in vm.hotels track by hotelIndex">
    <div ng-repeat="tag in vm.hTags[hotelIndex]">
      {{tag}}
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I see you used AngularJS v1.2.23 and my version is the latest one, AngularJS v1.6.3,,, it could be due that

Comment: @user1751287 [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/K3n7ZtLL8emDE9kVYAPZ?p=preview) using `v1.6.3`.. still no logs

Comment: I see the problem I loop over results on controller and return one array at the time that should match index while you return multidimensional array

Comment: @user1751287 didn't quite get it. If you still have problem, edit question with exact code and error

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.hotels = [{
    tags: "tag1|tag2|tag3"
  }, {
    tags: "tag4|tag5|tag6"
  }]
  vm.hTags = [["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <div ng-repeat="key in vm.hotels">
    <div ng-repeat="tag in vm.hTags[$index]">
      {{tag}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.hotels">
    <div ng-repeat="tag in vm.hTags[key]">
      {{tag}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried it but it still throws duplicates error .... Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] .. I use the latest version of angular 1.6.3 and I see you used earlier one. it may be the problem with that

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code change below,

```
<li ng-repeat="item in vm.hotels track by $index">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="tag in vm.hTags[$index]">
            {{tag}}   
        </li>
    </ul>
<li>
```

Check and let me know.You made a syntax error

Comment: sorry I had a typo within my code, just edited...no it does not work

Comment: can you share your json structure here

Comment: I added how object property looks like above 0:object
  tags:"tag1||tag2", 1:object tags:"tag1||tag2"

Comment: Just add track by $index in inner ng-repeat

Comment: no it does not work as it then only takes the first tag from an array not all of them and displays each letter as a tag